# PHP HTTP Header appears multiple times with the same message

Tags: php, http-headers

I have a page named as add_administrator.php in this php i am checking if the status value is given using the GET method and if so that display the header with the value in status Now i am getting the value form a page add_administrator_code.php But the problem is that i am getting the header more then once i.e. Three times with the same message What should i do?

here is the add_administrator.php

```
<?php
session_start();
session_regenerate_id(true);//regenerating session id on every reload or refresh so to avoid the session hijack
  if (isset($_GET['status'])) {
        $sta = $_GET['status'];
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$sta');</script>";
        }

  if($_SESSION['alogin'])
    {
            }
        else    
    {
        header("location:../index.php");
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang=""> 
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Smart Ambulance</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/themify-icons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/flag-icon.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/cs-skin-elastic.css">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap-select.less"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/scss/style.css">
    <link href="assets/css/lib/vector-map/jqvmap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

 <!-- Fav and touch icons -->
  <?php include 'logo.php';?>
</head>
<body>


        <!-- Left Panel -->

    <aside id="left-panel" class="left-panel"style="background-color:#004466">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-default">
            <?php include 'left_menu.php';?>
        </nav>
    </aside><!-- /#left-panel -->

    <!-- Left Panel -->

    <!-- Right Panel -->

    <div id="right-panel" class="right-panel">

        <!-- Header-->
        <header id="header" class="header">

            <?php include 'header_menu.php';?>

        </header><!-- /header -->
        <!-- Header-->

        <div class="breadcrumbs">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="page-header float-left">
                    <div class="page-title">
                        <h1>Dashboard</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <div class="page-header float-right">
                    <div class="page-title">
                        <ol class="breadcrumb text-right">
                            <li class="active">Dashboard / User Details / Adminsitrator / Add</li>
                        </ol>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content mt-3">
        <!--********************************************** Content Start **********************************************-->
                  <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="card">
                      <div class="card-header">
                        <strong>Add Adminsitrator</strong> 
                      </div>
                      <div class="card-body card-block">
                        <form action="add_administrator_code.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
                          <div class="row form-group">
                            <!--<div class="col col-md-3"><label class=" form-control-label">Static</label></div>  -->
                            <div class="col-12 col-md-9">
                              <!-- <p class="form-control-static">Username</p>  -->                       
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="row form-group">
                            <div class="col col-md-3"><label for="text-input" class=" form-control-label">Name</label></div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-md-9"><input type="text" id="adm_name" name="adm_name" placeholder="Name" class="form-control"><small class="form-text text-muted"></small></div>
                          </div>
                            <div class="row form-group">
                            <div class="col col-md-3"><label for="email-input" class=" form-control-label">Contact Number</label></div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-md-9"><input type="text" id="adm_mob" name="adm_mob" placeholder="Enter Contact Number" class="form-control"><small class="help-block form-text"></small></div>
                          </div>

                          <div class="row form-group">
                            <div class="col col-md-3"><label for="email-input" class=" form-control-label">Email Id</label></div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-md-9"><input type="email" id="adm_mail_id" name="adm_mail_id" placeholder="Enter Email" class="form-control"><small class="help-block form-text"></small></div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="row form-group">
                            <div class="col col-md-3"><label for="password-input" class=" form-control-label">Password</label></div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-md-9"><input type="password" id="adm_pass" name="adm_pass" placeholder="Password" class="form-control"><small class="help-block form-text">Press the Generate Button to generate password</small></div>


                          </div>


                            <div class="row form-group">
                           <div align =center class="col col-md-1"><input type="checkbox"  onclick="togglepassword()" ></div>
                          <label for="text-input" class=" form-control-label">Show Password</label>

                        </div>
                            <div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
                          <i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i> Submit
                        </button>
                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                          <i class="fa fa-ban"></i> Reset</i>
                        </button>
                         <button type="button" onclick="generate()" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Generate</button>
                      </div>
                    </div> 

        <!--********************************************** Content End **********************************************-->
        </div>
    </div><!-- /#right-panel -->

    <!-- Right Panel -->

    <script src="assets/js/vendor/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/plugins.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>


    <script src="assets/js/lib/chart-js/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/dashboard.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/widgets.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/lib/vector-map/jquery.vmap.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/lib/vector-map/jquery.vmap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/lib/vector-map/jquery.vmap.sampledata.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/lib/vector-map/country/jquery.vmap.world.js"></script>
    <script>
        ( function ( $ ) {
            "use strict";

            jQuery( '#vmap' ).vectorMap( {
                map: 'world_en',
                backgroundColor: null,
                color: '#ffffff',
                hoverOpacity: 0.7,
                selectedColor: '#1de9b6',
                enableZoom: true,
                showTooltip: true,
                values: sample_data,
                scaleColors: [ '#1de9b6', '#03a9f5' ],
                normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'
            } );
        } )( jQuery );
    </script>   
<script>
            function togglepassword() {
              var x = document.getElementById("adm_pass");
              if (x.type === "password") {
                x.type = "text";
              } else {
                x.type = "password";
              }

            } 
            </script>
            <script>
function generate(){

    //set password length/complexity
    let complexity = 8;

    //possible password values
    let values = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWZYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890!@#$%^&*()_+";

    let password = "";

    //create for loop to choose password characters
    for(var i = 0; i <= complexity; i++){
        password = password + values.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(values.length - 1)));
    }

    //add password to textbox/display area
    document.getElementById("adm_pass").value = password;


}



</script>

</body>
</html>
```

here is the add_administrator_code.php

```
<?php include '../database.php'; 

// create a variable

$adm_name=$_POST['adm_name'];
$adm_mob=$_POST['adm_mob'];
$adm_mail_id=$_POST['adm_mail_id'];
$adm_pass=$_POST['adm_pass'];

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO admin_details (adm_name,adm_mob,adm_mail_id,adm_pass)
                VALUES ('$adm_name','$adm_mob','$adm_mail_id','$adm_pass')");

    if(mysqli_affected_rows($con) > 0){
    $status = "New Admin added Sucessfully";
    header("location: add_administrator.php?status=".$status);
    } else {
    $status = "Error in adding New Admin";
    header("location: add_administrator.php?status=".$status);
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop the script after you redirect to make sure nothing else runs:

```
{
  header("location: ...");
  exit;
}
```

Also, your code is vulnerable to both XSS and SQL injection. Read about [escaping HTML](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) and [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: I did put exit after the header as you mentioned but it didn't worked then i put exit in the echo statement of script it did managed to stop the mutliple header but it didnot redirect when blank

Answer (score 0):

for preventing loop the session start: instead of

```
session_start();
session_regenerate_id(TRUE);
```

change to this:

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
    session_regenerate_id(TRUE);
}
```

update me with the result,

> Note: dont forget to normalize the $_GET method for the security
>   improvement

Comment: it do not helped but i have a question for you what is normalizing of Get method?

Comment: i mean you need to improve the security of what you are getting via($_GET), for example if you want to store the get in the database you need to check if the $_GET is not some kind of bad script, validation is very impotent in the form